# How I open .s assembly file in Linux?

Tags: c, assembly, c-preprocessor, cc

I wrote my c program add.c, then preprocessed with cpp, then compiled with CC to obtain an add.s file. Now I would like to open it to see the assembly code. Can't find a way to do it.

Comment: they're normal text files, so use your favorite editor, like vim or geany etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.s` files are basically assembler *source* files, so you can pretty much open them in whatever tool you used to create the `.c` files in the first place.

In other words, mere mortals will opt for `Notepad++` or `Emacs`, but the true intelligentsia will use `Vim` :-)

Comment: i'm tempted to downvote just for mentioning Emacs :-P

Comment: Yeah thank you you're right, the problem was that it told me that I couldn't, because there must have happened something wrong during compilation. I treid to use cc, typing on terminal cc add.c -o add.s but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Gabriele, `cc add.c -o add.s` will almost certainly still create an executable file, it will just *call* it `add.s`. In other words, it won't be a text file assembler listing at all. You need to figure out what command line option tells your compiler to create the `.s` file rather than an executable. For example, `gcc -S add.c` will produce `add.s` for you (without needing to specify the actual output file explicitly) - it's the `-S` that does that for you.

Comment: @paxdiablo Hi thank you for explaining to me. I'm a newbie and still don't get why i can generate an executable and call it add.s. Isn't ".s" the extension anymore, is it  just part of the name of the file?

Comment: @Gabriele, you can usually *call* a file whatever you want (within the constraints of the file system). Consider, for example, renaming a file such as with `ren something.txt something_else.exe`. That text file doesn't magically become something you can execute just because you changed its name. That's especially so in UNIX-like systems (as opposed to Windows) since the extension is far less important there - it's more convention than something required.

Comment: @paxdiablo! Thank you very much! I believe to have understood! Great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

For getting .s file.
if you have main.cpp file , just complile with **g++ -S main.cpp** for getting main.s file.

Now you can open with **vim main.s**